# The counterpart of "inside"

Tags: single-word-requests, prepositions

If X is inside something, what is that something's relationship to X?

> The dog is inside the house.
>   → The house is _ _ _ _ the dog.

I was thinking of *around*, but it really sounds ugly, and it hardly works when *inside* isn't a cavern of some sort ("I'm in the park, the park is around me").

Comment: You *might* get away with saying, "I'm surrounded by the park" if you are in the centre of that space or enclosure. But the phrase: *The dog is surrounded by the house* doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

There isn’t one, because we don’t need one. *Around the dog* or *around me* may or may not be ‘ugly’, but it just isn’t something anyone would say in that kind of context.

Answer (score 0):

Barrie is right (in the contexts you describe) - but do you  mean to say ***enclose***?